# Sort pie chart's slices without sorting the data in the columns

Tags: google-sheets, charts

I haven't found something similar to that on the web, and it seems that the only way for the data to be sorted on the pie chart is if they're pre-sorted.
The problem is that I have a sheet populated by a third party software (Typeform) that places random data, which I then aggregate to present to the pie chart.

More specifically, Typeform writes

```
 town   | salary | cost
London  | 1000   | 500
Bristol | 700    | 300
London  | 900    | 400
Leeds   | 600    | 200
Leeds   | 500    | 300
Leeds   | 400    | 200
```

Then I aggregate the data in another sheet (Sheet2) so that I have

```
town   |  occurrences
London      2
Bristol     1
Leeds       3
```

Obviously the pie chart will draw London first, then Bristol, and then Leeds. These are only 3 entries, however in my example, I have 20, and the data in the pie chart are not ordered.

Sheet2's data cannot be sorted descending since I am using `=UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A)` and then in the column next to it `=countif(Sheet1!A:A,A2)` to populate them from the Sheet1 where the 3rd party software is writing them, in fact when I select them and click sort they don't get sorted, they reappear as they were.

Is there any way to sort them (and keep them sorted) in Sheet2, or by writing them in a new sheet?

Answer (score 4):

If `town` is in A1 of Sheet1 please try:

```
=query(Sheet1!A2:D7, "select A, count(C) group by A")
```

[image: SO33597438 first example]

[image: SO33597438 second example]

Comment: I already do that further down to do some more analysis, however this doesn't get me the data sorted, data just appears in random order.

Comment: Remember the main problem is how to sort the pie chart's data, not how I aggregate them.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Typeform data is in Sheet1!A:C, the following function in Sheet2!A1 should do the trick:

```
=QUERY("Sheet1!A:C","select A, count(B) order by count(B) desc",1)
```

Answer (score -3):

another way to do it is to simply apply Filter on your data, then sort from A-Z (for lowest-highest percentage) or Z-A (for highest-lowest percentage).

Then you create your PIE chart out of that and it comes out sorted!